# Why isn't Cloud Code honoring my cloudbuild.yaml file but gcloud beta builds submit is?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-code

I am using Google's Cloud Code extension with Visual Studio Code to use GCP's Cloud Build and deploy to a local kubernetes cluster (Docker Desktop). I have directed Cloud Build to run unit tests after installing modules.

When I build using the command line `gcloud beta builds submit`, the Cloud Build does the module install and successfully fails to build because I intentionally wrote a failing unit test. So that's great.

However, when I try to build and deploy using the Cloud Code extension, it is not using my cloudbuild.yaml at all. I know this because the

1.) The build succeeds even with the failing unit test

2.) No logging from the unit test appears in GCP logging

3.) I completely deleted cloudbuild.yaml and the build / deploy still succeeded, which seems to imply Cloud Code is using Dockerfile

What do I need to do to ensure Cloud Code uses cloudbuild.yaml for its build/deploy to a local instance of kubernetes?

Thanks!

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```yaml
steps:
- name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']
- id: "test"
  name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['test']
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

**scaffold.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta19
kind: Config
build:
  tagPolicy:
    sha256: {}
  artifacts:
  - context: .
    image: genesys-gencloud-dev
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - kubernetes-manifests/**
profiles:
- name: cloudbuild
  build:
    googleCloudBuild: {}
```

**launch.json**

```json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Kubernetes: Run/Debug - cloudbuild",
      "type": "cloudcode.kubernetes",
      "request": "launch",
      "skaffoldConfig": "${workspaceFolder}\\skaffold.yaml",
      "profile": "cloudbuild",
      "watch": true,
      "cleanUp": false,
      "portForward": true,
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "imageRegistry": "gcr.io/my-gcp-project",
      "debug": [
        {
          "image": "my-image-dev",
          "containerName": "my-container-dev",
          "sourceFileMap": {
            "${workspaceFolder}": "/WORK_DIR"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to edit your `skaffold.yaml` file to use Cloud Build:

```
build:
  googleCloudBuild: {}
```

See https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/builders/#remotely-on-google-cloud-build for more details.

**EDIT**: It looks like your skaffold.yaml enables cloud build for the `cloudbuild` profile, but that the profile isn't active.

Some options:

- Add `"profile": "cloudbuild"` to your `launch.json` for 'Run on Kubernetes'.
  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atgOw.png)
- Move the `googleCloudBuild: {}` to the top-level `build:` section. (In other words, skip using the profile)
- Activate the profile using one of the other methods from https://skaffold.dev/docs/environment/profiles/#activation

**UDPATE** (from asker)

I needed to do the following:

1. Update `skaffold.yaml` as follows. In particular note the `image`, field under build > artifacts, and `projectId` field under profiles > build.

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta19
kind: Config
build:
  tagPolicy:
    sha256: {}
  artifacts:
  - context: .
    image: gcr.io/my-project-id/my-image
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - kubernetes-manifests/**
profiles:
- name: cloudbuild
  build:
    googleCloudBuild:
      projectId: my-project-id
```

2. Run this command to activate the profile: `skaffold dev -p cloudbuild`

Comment: Looks like I already have it. I will update my question to include my `scaffold.yaml`

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I appreciate you digging in to help me figure this out. Unfortunately, `"profile":"cloudbuild"` is already in my `launch.json` file as well. I will post in my question after some redaction of names.

Comment: Oh, I missed the activate profile step. I will give that a shot!

Comment: I think this solved my issue -- but I'm running into another bug I have a case with Google support opened for. I'm going to update your answer with what I had to do with `skaffold.yaml` and the skaffold CLI.